# What makes a torpedo roll unique

Tags: bread, sandwich

In New York I've had assorted sandwiches on "Torpedo rolls". They are quite unique in flavor and texture unto themselves.  I am a hobbyist baker and can't seem to figure them out. Anyone know what technique or ingredient makes them what they are?

Comment: What kind of place have you had them from? Italian, Vietnamese etc?

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need more details. In what way are they unique in flavour and texture?

Comment: Do you have any examples of recipes you've tried? Could you tell us what about them didn't come out how you wanted? Even if someone knows exactly how to make New York style torpedo rolls, it could be hard for them to guess what you're missing. (Elendil and Mien: The OP is pretty definitely talking about the torpedo rolls used for traditional deli sandwiches - think Italian sub sandwiches if you have to. I haven't been there myself but I'm sure plenty of people know exactly what the OP wants.)

Comment: @jefromi ok, well, I didn't, hence the question :)

Comment: They were largely Italian sausage sandwiches.  They were light,  like a cross between a croissant and a baguette. Not buttery and soft crusted.  They seemed to be on about every stand I hit.  Sub rolls, bread, or torpedos. Had a couple subs and the roll was different.  Asked a couple guys and they just pick em at the bakery they don't make em. Unfortunately, never noticed a bakery to stop into.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the midwest we have a few restaurant chains that serve torpedo sandwiches, aka gondolas---if they're similar to what you describe, they use sugar in the dough. You can find Avanti's bread recipes online; my family usually adds more sugar than what's called for.